# A user can explore(see) any page in wagtail admin interface?

Tags: django, content-management-system, wagtail

Issue:

The site structure is as following:

```
Homepage
  |- Blog Index
  |- Event Index
  |- People
  |- Contact Page
  |- User A
       |- Test Page 1
       |- Test Page 2
```

Now I add a user called 'UserA', who belongs to roles group of 'UserA' (the same name), and group 'UserA' is set to only has 'add' & 'publish' permissions to 'User A' page.

The left nav bar in admin area works fine, 'UserA' can only see 'User A' as the root; But when clicking on the wagtail bird icon in admin page, 'UserA' can see Homepage and all its children, like 'Blog Index' and 'Event Index'.

So it's like a user can view any pages in Wagtail admin area? Is this on purpose?

What I really expect is a user can only see(explore) pages owned by himself, or pages that his role group has access to. It's like user isolation. Can this be done? Thanks.

---

Project: wagtail-demo

Python: 3.6.1
Django: 1.10
Wagtail: 1.10.1